# global behavior of an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE system 
$$
(x',y')=f(x,y)
$$
where
$$
f(x,y)=((1-x/2-y/2)x,(-1/4+x/2)y)
$$
in the first (open) quadrant.

It is not hard to show that $z_0=(1/2,3/2)$, which is a equilibrium of the system, is *locally* a spiral sink.

Using Mathematica, one can get

[image]

Let $\phi_t(z) = (x(t),y(t))$ be the  solution to the system with initial condition $(x(0),y(0))=z$ in the first quadrant.
One can tell from the figure that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi_t(z)=z_0
$$
for *every* $z$ in the first quadrant.

How can one *prove* that this is indeed true?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Lotka--Volterra type model:
$$
\dot x=x(a-bx-cy),\\
\dot y=y(-d-ey+fx).
$$
Here $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are non-negative parameters. Let $(\hat{x},\hat{y})$ be the unique  equilibrium in interior of $\mathbf R^2_+=\{(x,y)\in\mathbf R^2\colon x\geq 0,\,y\geq 0\}$ (it is unique because the isoclines are straight lines and can intersect at most at one point).

Consider
$$
V(x,y)=f(\hat x\log x-x)+c(\hat y\log y-y)
$$
and show that it is a Lyapunov-type function in $\mathbf R^2_+$. In particular show that the derivative of $V$ along the orbits is negative definite everywhere in interior of $\mathbf R^2_+$ except for $(\hat{x},\hat{y})$. Conclude, using the invariance principle, that this equilibrium is globally asymptotically stable in $\mathbf R^2_+$

Comment: Did you get something out of the answer?